# Python: Remove values in a 2D array that don't appear in separate 1D list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array, for example:

```
array = np.array([[0,1,0,0,4,0,5,0,0],
[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,2],
[1,1,0,0,3,0,0,2,2],
[0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0],
[6,6,0,0,0,0,7,7,7]])
```

I also have a list, for example:

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 7]
```

I want to remove (set to zero) all values in the array that do not appear in the list. For example:

```
newarray = [[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
            [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2]
            [1 1 0 0 3 0 0 2 2]
            [0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0]
            [0 0 0 0 0 0 7 7 7]
```

Here, the 4s, 5s, and 6s in the array have been replaced with 0s because they didn't appear in the list. My current solution is pretty slow using np.where() in a loop to remove all values in the array that don't appear in the list:

```
# get all unique values in array
unique_vals_in_array = np.unique(array)

# get all values in array that don't appear in list
vals_not_in_array = set(unique_vals_in_array) - set(list)

# On each loop, replace the values that do not appear in list with zero
for i in vals_not_in_array:
  new_array = np.where(array==i,0,array)
```

If anyone has a more efficient, pythonic solution I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `numpy` way to do this seems to be to use `isin`:

```
to_keep = [0, 1, 2, 3, 7]
result = np.where(np.isin(array, to_keep, invert=True), 0, array)
```

Here, `invert` returns the logical `not` of the result, so the statement says if the element in `array` is `not` in `to_keep` then it is replaced with 0. This will probably be a faster method than using a non-numpy solution.

Comment: Proper testing should probably consider the behaviour with varying sizes of input array and to-keep values.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Would you recommend I remove my comments on speed? Or even just everything after `timeit`? I think I'll leave up the answer with the "numpy way" of doing this, but I believe your answer is better.

Comment: Following @KarlKnechtel comment, I tested the solutions for my actual data with the following results:
list length: 123
array shape: (1, 602, 3600)
Original solution took 1.6121721267700195s
np.isin solution took 0.10941171646118164s
Karl's solution took 0.13035941123962402s

Comment: @jruss I'm glad the numpy solution worked out well!

Comment: I expected the `np.isin` approach to be fastest in the long run; I'm not especially experienced with Numpy and didn't feel like reasoning out anything more sophisticated than my own solution. It's think it's best that the timing results are made available in an answer, and I also think it's possible that we've both overlooked something.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just iterate over the list and add the values back in to a result array?

```
result = np.zeros_like(array)

for to_keep in [0, 1, 2, 3, 7]:
    result[array==to_keep] = to_keep
```